# Priority queue - time queue

Tags: c, linux, data-structures

I'm trying to build a timer queue in C to save the jobs that need to be processed based on time, is priority queue the best thing here or is there something else I need to look at?

The following is what I have,

```
job 1, start_time, time_to_exec, execute after 5 minutes 
job 2, start_time, time_to_exec, execute after 5 minutes 
Then new job came in 
job 3, start_time, time_to_exec, execute after 1 minutes 
...
and so on
```

and I'll be checking the first element every few microseconds.

start_time is the time before entering the queue.

time_to_exec is the time that will be used to insert the job into the queue

Comment: Could you explain what `start_time` and `time_to_exec` mean?

Comment: start_time is the time of the job just before entering the queue, the time to exec is the time that will be used to put the job in the queue

Comment: so `execute after n minutes` means `n == time_to_exec - start_time`?